# Laravel + Docker Доступ к БД вне контейнера

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-compose

Собственно вопрос заключается из САБЖА.

Имеется развернутый контейнер с приложением Laravel 
Также контейнер с Nginx.

Однако одно из основных условий, необходимо подключаться к Базе Данных которая находиться НЕ В ДОКЕРЕ, а просто стоит на этом же сервере.

Как это можно сделать ?

Примеры файлов: 
**app.dockerfile**

```
FROM php:7-fpm
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libmcrypt-dev mysql-client \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql \
    && pecl install mcrypt-1.0.1 docker-php-ext-enable mcrypt
WORKDIR /var/www/main_project/s_crm
```

**web.dockerfile**

```
   FROM nginx:1.10
ADD ./vhost.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
WORKDIR /var/www/main_project/s_crm
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
    version: '2'

services: 
    web: 
      build: 
        context: ./
        dockerfile: web.dockerfile
      volumes:
        - ./:/var/www/main_project/s_crm
      ports:
        - "8080:80"
      links:
        - app
    app: 
      build:
        context: ./
        dockerfile: app.dockerfile
      volumes:
        - ./:/var/www/main_project/s_crm
```

**vhost.conf**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    index index.php index.html;
    root /var/www/main_project/s_crm/public;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass app:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблему решили.

Доступ был организован на БД на другой машине - на ней создали пользователя и дали права на доступ к этой БД от этого юзера с адреса приложения

Answer (score 0):

Простейший способ указать для каждого сервиса:

```
network_mode: "host"
```

Это заставит их использовать не интерфейс по-умолчанию который создается docker-compose автоматически, а интерфейсы самой машины. А значит у тебя будет доступ к loopback интерфейсу (localhost) и всем приложениям что на нем запущены.